# bringing twitter bootsrap typeahead above modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

This is my situation,

how can I fix this?

[image]

**broswer.css**
tried to remove- but changed nothing

**I have two versions of modal.js
new one where typeahead is below the modal**

```
/* =========================================================
 * bootstrap-modal.js v2.0.1
 * http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals
 * =========================================================
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * ========================================================= */


!function( $ ){

  "use strict"

 /* MODAL CLASS DEFINITION
  * ====================== */

  var Modal = function ( content, options ) {
    this.options = options
    this.$element = $(content)
      .delegate('[data-dismiss="modal"]', 'click.dismiss.modal', $.proxy(this.hide, this))
  }

  Modal.prototype = {

      constructor: Modal

    , toggle: function () {
        return this[!this.isShown ? 'show' : 'hide']()
      }

    , show: function () {
        var that = this

        if (this.isShown) return

        $('body').addClass('modal-open')

        this.isShown = true
        this.$element.trigger('show')

        escape.call(this)
        backdrop.call(this, function () {
          var transition = $.support.transition && that.$element.hasClass('fade')

          !that.$element.parent().length && that.$element.appendTo(document.body) //don't move modals dom position

          that.$element
            .show()

          if (transition) {
            that.$element[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
          }

          that.$element.addClass('in')

          transition ?
            that.$element.one($.support.transition.end, function () { that.$element.trigger('shown') }) :
            that.$element.trigger('shown')

        })
      }

    , hide: function ( e ) {
        e && e.preventDefault()

        if (!this.isShown) return

        var that = this
        this.isShown = false

        $('body').removeClass('modal-open')

        escape.call(this)

        this.$element
          .trigger('hide')
          .removeClass('in')

        $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
          hideWithTransition.call(this) :
          hideModal.call(this)
      }

  }


 /* MODAL PRIVATE METHODS
  * ===================== */

  function hideWithTransition() {
    var that = this
      , timeout = setTimeout(function () {
          that.$element.off($.support.transition.end)
          hideModal.call(that)
        }, 500)

    this.$element.one($.support.transition.end, function () {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
      hideModal.call(that)
    })
  }

  function hideModal( that ) {
    this.$element
      .hide()
      .trigger('hidden')

    backdrop.call(this)
  }

  function backdrop( callback ) {
    var that = this
      , animate = this.$element.hasClass('fade') ? 'fade' : ''

    if (this.isShown && this.options.backdrop) {
      var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate

      this.$backdrop = $('<div class="modal-backdrop ' + animate + '" />')
        .appendTo(document.body)

      if (this.options.backdrop != 'static') {
        this.$backdrop.click($.proxy(this.hide, this))
      }

      if (doAnimate) this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth // force reflow

      this.$backdrop.addClass('in')

      doAnimate ?
        this.$backdrop.one($.support.transition.end, callback) :
        callback()

    } else if (!this.isShown && this.$backdrop) {
      this.$backdrop.removeClass('in')

      $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade')?
        this.$backdrop.one($.support.transition.end, $.proxy(removeBackdrop, this)) :
        removeBackdrop.call(this)

    } else if (callback) {
      callback()
    }
  }

  function removeBackdrop() {
    this.$backdrop.remove()
    this.$backdrop = null
  }

  function escape() {
    var that = this
    if (this.isShown && this.options.keyboard) {
      $(document).on('keyup.dismiss.modal', function ( e ) {
        e.which == 27 && that.hide()
      })
    } else if (!this.isShown) {
      $(document).off('keyup.dismiss.modal')
    }
  }


 /* MODAL PLUGIN DEFINITION
  * ======================= */

  $.fn.modal = function ( option ) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('modal')
        , options = $.extend({}, $.fn.modal.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
      if (!data) $this.data('modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
      else if (options.show) data.show()
    })
  }

  $.fn.modal.defaults = {
      backdrop: true
    , keyboard: true
    , show: true
  }

  $.fn.modal.Constructor = Modal


 /* MODAL DATA-API
  * ============== */

  $(function () {
    $('body').on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function ( e ) {
      var $this = $(this), href
        , $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) //strip for ie7
        , option = $target.data('modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())

      e.preventDefault()
      $target.modal(option)
    })
  })

}( window.jQuery );
```

**the old version, where typeahead is on top of the modal
but all the modals are opened on load.**

```
/* =========================================================
* bootstrap-modal.js v1.4.0
* http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modal
* =========================================================
* Copyright 2011 Twitter, Inc.
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
* ========================================================= */


!function ($) {

    "use strict"

    /* CSS TRANSITION SUPPORT (https://gist.github.com/373874)
    * ======================================================= */

    var transitionEnd

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.support.transition = (function () {
            var thisBody = document.body || document.documentElement
        , thisStyle = thisBody.style
        , support = thisStyle.transition !== undefined || thisStyle.WebkitTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MozTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MsTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.OTransition !== undefined
            return support
        })()

        // set CSS transition event type
        if ($.support.transition) {
            transitionEnd = "TransitionEnd"
            if ($.browser.webkit) {
                transitionEnd = "webkitTransitionEnd"
            } else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
                transitionEnd = "transitionend"
            } else if ($.browser.opera) {
                transitionEnd = "oTransitionEnd"
            }
        }

    })


    /* MODAL PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
    * ============================= */

    var Modal = function (content, options) {
        this.settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.modal.defaults, options)
        this.$element = $(content)
      .delegate('.close', 'click.modal', $.proxy(this.hide, this))

        if (this.settings.show) {
            this.show()
        }

        return this
    }

    Modal.prototype = {

        toggle: function () {
            return this[!this.isShown ? 'show' : 'hide']()
        }

    , show: function () {
        var that = this
        this.isShown = true
        this.$element.trigger('show')

        escape.call(this)
        backdrop.call(this, function () {
            var transition = $.support.transition && that.$element.hasClass('fade')

            that.$element
            .appendTo(document.body)
            .show()

            if (transition) {
                that.$element[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
            }

            that.$element.addClass('in')

            transition ?
            that.$element.one(transitionEnd, function () { that.$element.trigger('shown') }) :
            that.$element.trigger('shown')

        })

        return this
    }

    , hide: function (e) {
        e && e.preventDefault()

        if (!this.isShown) {
            return this
        }

        var that = this
        this.isShown = false

        escape.call(this)

        this.$element
          .trigger('hide')
          .removeClass('in')

        $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
          hideWithTransition.call(this) :
          hideModal.call(this)

        return this
    }

    }


    /* MODAL PRIVATE METHODS
    * ===================== */

    function hideWithTransition() {
        // firefox drops transitionEnd events :{o
        var that = this
      , timeout = setTimeout(function () {
          that.$element.unbind(transitionEnd)
          hideModal.call(that)
      }, 500)

        this.$element.one(transitionEnd, function () {
            clearTimeout(timeout)
            hideModal.call(that)
        })
    }

    function hideModal(that) {
        this.$element
      .hide()
      .trigger('hidden')

        backdrop.call(this)
    }

    function backdrop(callback) {
        var that = this
      , animate = this.$element.hasClass('fade') ? 'fade' : ''
        if (this.isShown && this.settings.backdrop) {
            var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate

            this.$backdrop = $('<div class="modal-backdrop ' + animate + '" />')
        .appendTo(document.body)

            if (this.settings.backdrop != 'static') {
                this.$backdrop.click($.proxy(this.hide, this))
            }

            if (doAnimate) {
                this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
            }

            this.$backdrop.addClass('in')

            doAnimate ?
        this.$backdrop.one(transitionEnd, callback) :
        callback()

        } else if (!this.isShown && this.$backdrop) {
            this.$backdrop.removeClass('in')

            $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
        this.$backdrop.one(transitionEnd, $.proxy(removeBackdrop, this)) :
        removeBackdrop.call(this)

        } else if (callback) {
            callback()
        }
    }

    function removeBackdrop() {
        this.$backdrop.remove()
        this.$backdrop = null
    }

    function escape() {
        var that = this
        if (this.isShown && this.settings.keyboard) {
            $(document).bind('keyup.modal', function (e) {
                if (e.which == 27) {
                    that.hide()
                }
            })
        } else if (!this.isShown) {
            $(document).unbind('keyup.modal')
        }
    }


    /* MODAL PLUGIN DEFINITION
    * ======================= */

    $.fn.modal = function (options) {
        var modal = this.data('modal')

        if (!modal) {

            if (typeof options == 'string') {
                options = {
                    show: /show|toggle/.test(options)
                }
            }

            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).data('modal', new Modal(this, options))
            })
        }

        if (options === true) {
            return modal
        }

        if (typeof options == 'string') {
            modal[options]()
        } else if (modal) {
            modal.toggle()
        }

        return this
    }

    $.fn.modal.Modal = Modal

    $.fn.modal.defaults = {
        backdrop: false
  , keyboard: false
  , show: false
    }


    /* MODAL DATA- IMPLEMENTATION
    * ========================== */

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').delegate('[data-controls-modal]', 'click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            var $this = $(this).data('show', true)
            $('#' + $this.attr('data-controls-modal')).modal($this.data())
        })
    })

} (window.jQuery || window.ender);
```

Comment: Odd. The [modal dialog styles](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/modals.less) seems to take popovers and dropdowns inside modals into account, so it should work, as far as I can tell

Comment: Can you post some code to take a look? your html perhaps?

Comment: I added, btw I used modal.js from bootsrap-xtra site. I tired to swap it with the same js from the site I took typeahead.js but it even got things worst.

Comment: @EladBenda Is there any relevant code in your `browser.css` that modifies any of the elements in the bootstrap? I made a simple test case [here](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/bvY8a/1/show/) and its all working fine for me, though i could not test it with your code.

Comment: I guess my modal.js is not the right one. I use another one but all modals are opened on startup. why?

Comment: @AndresIlich managed to reproduce: It happens when I refere modal.js from bootsrap-xtra. using modal.js from your jsfiddle opens all modal on page init. why is that ? http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/bvY8a/1/

Comment: @EladBenda i forgot to pass the `show : false` option on the modal call and add the `hide` class to the main div of the modal content. Once inserted all modals are hidden by default until called. [Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/bvY8a/2/) version. I'm still confused about your issue though, can you post a test case using the fiddle i provided?

Comment: here: http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/bvY8a/1/embedded/result/

Comment: @EladBenda tested the fiddle and its working fine for me, is it not working for you? If not, what browser are you testing in?

Comment: Chrome. How come it works for you? The two modal.js I brought here are so different. It work for me only with the second version

Comment: @EladBenda weird, the second version is the old one. Just take a look at my fiddle and try to match what you have to whats on it, http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/bvY8a/2/.

Comment: @AndresIlich I'm not sure if you're gonna read this because it's an old post, but your jsfiddle.net/andresilich/bvY8a/2. doesnt work. It only works when I put .typeahead{z-index: 1050;}

Comment: @Chanckjh hmm, dont remember what was the initial question :D i think that there were some changes to the bootstrap that made this solution not work but your fix definitely makes it work. this solution was for an early early version of the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the second version of modal.js and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index of .dropdown-menu to < 1050, which is the z-index of the modal.